# Turn every second character to uppercase using map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string and need to turn it to uppercase using map function. It would be something like this:

```js
var str = 'hello world how ya doing?';
function toUpperCase(str){
  return str.split('').map((v,i) =>  i%2 == 0 ? v[i].toLowerCase(): v[i].toUpperCase()).join('');
 }

console.log(toUpperCase(str));
```

But when I run it I get entire sentence in uppercase.

Comment: Please show your actual code. That one throws an error, it doesn't turn the entire sentence uppercase.

Comment: @OunknownO you should change your question title to 'every second character of the word'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v` argument holds actually every single letter inside the array, so using `v[i]` has no sense.

```js
var str = 'hello world how ya doing?';

function toUpperCase(str) {
  return str.split('').map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? v.toLowerCase() : v.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

console.log(toUpperCase(str));
```

I guess you meant to turn `upperCase` every second *letter*, but if you really care about whole word:

```js
var str = 'hello world how ya doing?';

function toUpperCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? v.toLowerCase() : v.toUpperCase()).join(' ');
}

console.log(toUpperCase(str));
```

Comment: That will convert every other character, not every other word. Change the `split` and `join` parameter to `' '` (a single space character) to fix it.

Comment: @MrWillihog I just thought that he desires every second letter to be upper case, but just in case I've added the alternative solution, with every second whole word to be upper case.

Comment: @OunknownO Just like I thought. (:

Comment: Your question is titled: 'Turn every second word to uppercase using map' I would change that to character for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var str = 'hello world how ya doing?';
var res = str.split(' ').map(function(v,i){
    return i%2 === 0 ? v.toLowerCase():v.toUpperCase()
});
console.log(res.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a single char from your array's value.

The parameter `val`  of `.map(function(val, i)` will be every single string in your array of words. I fixed your code, I hope it will clear to you:

```js
var str = 'hello world how ya doing?';

console.log(toUpperCase(str));

function toUpperCase(str){
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var uppers = words.map(function(val, i) {
    if(i%2 == 0)
      return (val + "").toLowerCase();
    else
      return (val + "").toUpperCase();
  });
  return uppers.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the given string in the array then Use 
[Array.prototype.map(),](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

then you can convert every second character using toUpperCase() function.

Have a look at below code:

```
 "hello world how ya doing"
      .split("")
      .map((s, i) => (i % 2 != 0 ? s.toUpperCase() : s))
      .join("");

    OUTPUT: "hElLo wOrLd hOw yA DoInG"
```

Comment: Add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.